# How to analyze BRFSS survey data in R? How to set `id`?

Tags: r, survey, weights

I am trying to analyze BRFSS in R with weights for complex survey design using the `survey` package. I am confused as to what to set `id` to. The BRFSS manual says to set `id` to 1 but I found other code online that recommends setting `id` to `psu`. When I run both to look at a single variable, I got the same answer so perhaps they are no different.

*Could you please explain if there is a difference between setting the `id` to 1 or setting it to `psu`?*

My current code looks as follows:

```
# Set options for allowing a single observation per stratum options
options(survey.lonely.psu = "adjust")
# Create survey design
brfssdsgn <- svydesign(
    id=~1,
    strata = ~ststr,
    weights = ~llcpwt,
    data = BRFSS)

brfss_design <-
    svydesign(
        id = ~ xpsu ,
        strata = ~ xststr ,
        data = brfss_df ,
        weight = ~ xllcpwt ,
        nest = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

set it to `psu`.  there's a mistake in the R code shown in

https://www.cdc.gov/brfss/annual_data/2017/pdf/Complex-Smple-Weights-Prep-Module-Data-Analysis-2017-508.pdf

their sas code and R code will not give the same results.  the sas code looks correct, and has the psu specified.

quoting from their text

```
In all cases, the variable _STSTR should be used for stratification,
and the variable _PSU should be used for clustering, in complex sampling analyses
```